# Algorithm to find an exact value in a hash table

Tags: java, search, compare, hashtable

For a class project, I am writing a spellchecker program using a hash table to store words in I am supposed to have it recognize when a letter has been either misplaced or omitted. This is very specific in the instructions so I cannot vary from it. That being said, I've come across an issue with searching the values in said hash table. For example, when I enter the word "te" it says I've spelled the word correctly because it's finding every single instance of those two letters together and saying "Yeah that's valid!"

My question: is there a way to have it search for ONLY what I've entered and ignore the other letters in the values?

My code for searching the hash table is as follows

```
Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\n---Enter a word to check the spelling: ");
String s = userIn.nextLine();
String p = s.toUpperCase();

p.trim();
if (hash.containsValue(p)) {
    System.out.println("\n" + p + " is spelled correctly");
} else {
    System.out.println("Apologies. That word is not found");
}
userIn.close();
System.out.println(p);
```

As requested: Here is the rest of my code that initializes and builds the hashtable and such

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> hash = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
String input;
ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
String line;
File allTheWords = new File("words.txt");

public void createTable() throws IOException {
    Scanner rd = new Scanner(allTheWords);
    int i = 0;
    while (rd.hasNextLine()) {
        line = rd.nextLine();
        hash.put(i, line.trim());
        i++;
    }

    rd.close();

    if (hash.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Sorry. The function did not work");
    }

    if (hash.size() > 0) {
        int len = hash.size();
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomKey = random.nextInt(len);
        System.out.println("Success! You created a hashtable!");

        String randomWord = new String(hash.get(randomKey));
        System.out.println("For example, line " + randomKey + " is " + randomWord);
    }
}

    
public void run() {
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\n---Enter a word to check the spelling: ");
    String s = userIn.nextLine();
    String p = s.toUpperCase();

    p.trim();
    if (hash.containsValue(p)) {
        System.out.println("\n" + p + " is spelled correctly");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Apologies. That word is not found");
    }
    userIn.close();
    System.out.println(p);
}
```

Comment: Can you five us a fully working example (with initialized variable `hash`)?

Comment: What is 'hash table' ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I cant reproduce the problem. I have tried it with a file containing the words: test, Text. If I enter "te" the word is not found.

Comment: Why do you search by value? It's completely inefficient as it's just iterating over everything. You are not even using the fact that you have hashing collection. Instead you should have those strings as keys. I'm not sure why you keep there indexes as well, but if you don't need them, then a Set would be much better option. In addition: you should always use HashMap instead of HashTable, there is no reason to pick HashTable, it's just fully thread-safe which makes it slower (for thread-safe Map there are better choices)

Comment: Don't use a `Hashtable`, because it's not useful, and besides you are not using it correctly. A`HashSet<String>` would be a good choice for your "dictionary". Load your words into the set and use its `contains()` method to look up words.

Comment: Well as stated in my original post, I have to use a hashtable for the assignment. It may not be the best way to do it but it's what's required for this.

Comment: As Mirek said, you can use the words as keys instead. You can then Call `containsKey(string)` to get the words instead of `containsValue` with your hashtable.

Comment: In `run` you are calling toUpperCase on the input, but not calling toUpperCase on all the words in `createTable`. You won't get proper matches. 

The question should include the complete minimal working example and sample "words.txt" and the sample input to test it, and the expected output. This allows us to check the code and even run it ourselves if necessary. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.